# Product rule in an Inner product Space

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

I have been working in the book "Differential Geometry
Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic
Classes" to Loring W. Tu.

My question is regarded excercise which yields:

- An inner product space $(V,\langle \ , \ \rangle)$ is automatically a normed vector space, with norm $\lVert v \rVert = \sqrt{\langle v , v \rangle}$. The **derivative** of function $f : \mathbb{R} \to V $ is defined to be
  $$
  f^{\prime}(t) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(t+h) - f(t)}{h},
  $$
  provided that the limit exists, where the limit is taken with respect to the norm $\lVert \ \rVert$. If $f,g : \mathbb{R} \to V$ are differentiable functions, show that $\langle f,g\rangle : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and
  $$
  \langle f,g\rangle^{\prime} = \langle f^{\prime},g\rangle + \langle f,g^{\prime}\rangle.
  $$

The way to prove it is similar to the product rule in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. But I am stuck with taking the deriviative with resp. to the norm an later in proving the product rule. Can someone explain the steps or proof?

Comment: Use the fact that the definition with the limit is equivalent with the formulation $f(t+h) = f(t) + hf'(t) + o(h)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

$$\frac{\langle f,g\rangle(t+h)-\langle f,g\rangle(t)}{h} = \frac{\langle f(t+h),g(t+h)\rangle-\langle f(t),g(t)\rangle}{h} = \frac{\langle f(t+h),g(t+h)\rangle-\langle f(t),g(t+h)\rangle+\langle f(t),g(t+h)\rangle-\langle f(t),g(t)\rangle}{h} = \frac{\langle f(t+h)-f(t),g(t+h)\rangle+\langle f(t),g(t+h)-g(t)\rangle}{h} = \left\langle\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h},g(t+h)\right\rangle + \left\langle f(t),\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}\right\rangle$$

Now you can show that $$\lim_{h\to0}\left\langle\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h},g(t+h)\right\rangle=\langle f'(t),g(t)\rangle$$ and $$\lim_{h\to0}\left\langle f(t),\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}\right\rangle=\langle f(t),g'(t)\rangle$$ because both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is continuous. Then it follows that the limit $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\langle f,g\rangle(t+h)-\langle f,g\rangle(t)}{h}$$ exists and is equal to $\langle f'(t),g(t)\rangle+\langle f(t),g'(t)\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help!